# Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring such that distinct ideals of $R$ have distinct orders (size). Is $R$ a PIR?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring such that distinct ideals of $R$ have distinct orders (size). Is $R$ a Principal Ideal Ring (PIR) ? What if we moreover assume that distinct subrings of $R$ have distinct orders ?

Comment: Do you have specific reasons to think so ?

Comment: @CaptainLama : Well just only an analogy ; I know that if $G$ is a finite group such that distinct subgroups of $G$ have distinct orders then $G$ is cyclic  ...

Answer (score 0):

A finite commutative ring (indeed, any artinian commutative ring) is a finite direct product of local rings, and a finite direct product of principal ideal rings is a principal ideal ring, so it's enough to prove that a finite local commutative ring with all ideals of different sizes is a principal ideal ring.

Let $R$ be such a ring. Since it is local, up to isomorphism it has a unique simple module $S$, with $\vert S\vert=d$, say. If
$$0=I_0<I_1<\dots<I_n=R$$
is a composition series, then $I_i/I_{i-1}\cong S$ for $i>0$, and so $\vert I_i\vert=d^i$. There must be a unique such composition series, since another one would give us two different ideals of size $d^i$ for some $i$. Hence $I_0,\dots,I_n$ are the only ideals of $R$. So if we pick $x\in I_i\setminus I_{i-1}$ then the ideal generated by $x$ must be $I_i$, and so $R$ is a principal ideal ring.

Comment: so you can always get a composition series because the ring is finite ?

Comment: @users Yes. If a chain of ideals is not a composition series then you can insert another ideal somewhere in the chain. If you keep doing this then the process must terminate since $R$ is finite, and then you have a composition series.

Comment: Would it be enough to assume Artinian to get a composition series ? but then perhaps the quotients $I_i/I_{i-1}$ need not be finite , right ?

Comment: @users Yes, any finitely generated module for an Artinian ring has a composition series. And yes, the quotients may not be finite, as an Artinian ring can have infinite simple modules.